# SQL : Two Columns Count Third Column Sum of 1st and 2nd Column

Tags: sql, oracle, count, sum

im trying to create two columns thats counting different items and then on the Third Column SUM up column 1 and 2. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

```
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(ecarrno) Conventional FROM L16T3
     WHERE (l16lcode = 46) AND
        (l46adr IN ('680', '657','693','623','639','704','644','679'))),
    (SELECT COUNT(admunit) Auto FROM L16T3
    WHERE (admunit= 16AP) AND
        (l46adr IN ('611','618','637','638'))),
    SUM (COUNT(ecarrno) + COUNT(admunit))
    FROM L16T3
    AND DATREG >= @('START DATE',datreg)  
    AND DATREG <= @('END DATE',datreg)
ORDER BY datreg 
DESC,l16seqno DESC
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read. (And to write, without errors.)

Comment: And what is wrong with your current query?  If you just need table level counts, then what you have should be fine.

Comment: Hi @TimBiegeleisen, first of all thanks for editing. For some reason im having an error. 
Error when executing Sql
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
--> Error at offset: 295

Comment: What does this mean? `@('START DATE',datreg)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation and a subquery.  The query looks something like this:

```
SELECT Conventional, Auto, (Conventional + Auto)
FROM (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN l16lcode = 46 AND l46adr IN ('680', '657', '693', '623', '639', '704', '644', '679')
                      THEN 1 ELSE 0
                 END) as Conventional,
             SUM(CASE WHEN admunit = '16AP' AND l46adr IN ('611', '618', '637', '638')
                      THEN 1 ELSE 0
                 END) as Auto
      FROM L16T3 l
     WHERE DATREG >= @('START DATE', datreg)   AND DATREG <= @('END DATE', datreg)     
    ) l
ORDER BY datreg ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation

```
SELECT sum(case when l16lcode = 46 and l46adr IN ('680', '657','693','623','639','704','644','679') then 1 else 0 end )col1, 
       sum(case when admunit= 16AP and l46adr IN ('611','618','637','638') then 1 else 0 end ) col2, 
    sum(case when l16lcode = 46 and l46adr IN ('680', '657','693','623','639','704','644','679') then 1 else 0 end )+
       sum(case when admunit= 16AP and l46adr IN ('611','618','637','638') then 1 else 0 end ) col3

        FROM L16T3
        where DATREG >= @('START DATE',datreg)  
        AND DATREG <= @('END DATE',datreg)
```